# How would I integrate $(x^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I need to find $\int(x^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}dx.$ I started by trying to split it into $\int (x^2+1)(x^2+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}dx$ and then integrating by parts but that didn't seem to be working out. Is there a better way to go about it?

Comment: You could try using trig substitution.

Comment: So substitute $x=tan(u)$?

Comment: A trigonometric substitution won’t work. You need to use a hyperbolic substitution instead. Please refer to [this article](http://homepages.lboro.ac.uk/~maak2/intechpdf/alg/sinhsub.pdf).

Comment: @BerrickFillmore You're wrong about that; as Kaj Hansen has pointed out, the integral can be converted to $\int \sec(\theta)^5 d \theta$, which can be attacked by integration by parts (although the computation is not that easy). You're right that a hyperbolic substitution is easier, however.

Comment: @Ian: I doubt the veracity of your claim.

Comment: @BerrickFillmore See #3: http://archives.math.utk.edu/visual.calculus/4/recursion.2/ The actual conversion to the trigonometric form is quite simple, as Kaj Hansen showed.

Comment: @Ian: In that case, I stand corrected. :)

Answer (score 3):

Setting $x=\sinh(t)$, we obtain
$$I = \int (x^2+1)^{3/2}dx = \int \cosh^3(t) \cosh(t)dt = \int \cosh^4(t)dt = \int \left(\dfrac{e^t + e^{-t}}2\right)^4dt$$
This gives us
$$16I = \int \left(e^{4t} + 4e^{2t} + 6 + 4e^{-2t} + e^{-4t}\right)dt = 2 \int \cosh(4t)dt + 8 \int \cosh(2t)dt + 6t + \text{const}$$
I trust you can finish from here making use of the fact that
$$\int \cosh(at)dt = \dfrac{\sinh(at)}a$$

Answer (score 2):

Try the substitution $x = \tan(\theta)$.  Then $x^2 + 1 = \tan^2(\theta) + 1 = \sec^2(\theta)$.

Since $dx = \sec^2(\theta) \ d\theta$, then after simplifying your integral becomes:

$$\int \sec^5(\theta) d \theta$$

---

Alternatively, you can try a hyperbolic trig substitution that, e.g., user17762 suggests.

Comment: The problem with $\sec$ and $\tan$ is that both are ugly functions to handle with singularities. Dealing with hyperbolic functions is nicer especially for integration purposes. For instance, it is still slightly non-trivial to integrate $\sec^5(\theta)$.

Comment: Oh no doubt @user17762.  It's not something that I'd want to do, but I know I could if I had to.  It's good for pedagogical reasons to see multiple ways of going about things, but I admit that your approach is easier (+1).

Answer (score 0):

To carry out your original idea, proceed as follows:
$$ \int (1+x^2)^{n/2} \, dx = \int x^2 (1+x^2)^{n/2-1} \, dx + \int (1+x^2)^{(n-2)/2} \, dx $$
Integrating the first by parts,
$$ \int x^2 (1+x^2)^{n/2-1} \, dx = \frac{1}{n}x(1+x^2)^{n/2} -\frac{1}{n} \int (1+x^2)^{n/2} \, dx, $$
so rearranging gives
$$ \int (1+x^2)^{n/2} \, dx = \frac{1}{n+1}x(1+x^2)^{n/2} + \frac{n}{n+1}\int (1+x^2)^{(n-2)/2} \, dx $$
Applying this a couple of times to your integral gets us to
$$ \int (1+x^2)^{3/2} \, dx = \frac{1}{4}x(1+x^2)^{3/2} + \frac{3}{4} \left( \frac{1}{2}x(1+x^2)^{1/2} + \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} \right), $$
and the last integral is equal to $ \arg\sinh{x} $, basically by the inverse function rule.